Highlight scope when matching bracket
Is there a way to highlight the scope of a bracket when the cursor is next to it?
Recently, I have been playing around with Dr Racket (IDE for racket language) and I noticed a really convenient and cool feature for quickly visualization of its scope.
Since racket uses mostly "(" and ")" , having these nested is a nightmare but this feature makes it so easy to complete the pair bracket.
I just wonder if there is something similar to this in VScode otherwise I will have to create my own extension.
I tried finding this feature in the marketplace and vscode settings but did not find any similar feature to this.
